# Multiple Mule applications are receiving the same message running on different ports

Tags: mule

**The setup**: Several Mule apps (at least 4) running under ESB 3.8.1 CE are deployed with inbound endpoints listening on different ports. Each links a unique .NET application with distinct Salesforce instances. Each listener has SOAP endpoints with an identical webmethod to POST to (although the WSDL's themselves are not necessarily).

**The mystery**: When one of the endpoints is called directly (url:19001, say) the message is processed by that Mule inbound listener, correctly logging the call along with its arguments and dispatching it to flows within that application. That SAME message is also picked up by other inbound listeners (with endpoints of url:19004, url:19007 and url:19010, say) which also log this call (and ultimately fail) simultaneously.

In my time-consuming attempts to track the cause of this behavior I've found this sort of "cross talk" also happens on windows deployments. I've found that widening port ranges significantly has no effect either. The web seems to have nothing to offer in terms of explanation, this being the first S.O. question about it for example.

**The question**: What is going on? Has anyone else experienced this and how the heck do we stop it?

Comment: There's certainly an explanation for your problem (or you broke the internet, though I doubt it ;). Please provide more elements such as your flows and endpoints configurations and how you proceed to send your messages (such as the tool and method).

Comment: Using MSMQ to send SOAP notifications and I think the Multicast option is the true culprit. I haven't winnowed down the root cause of why this should be the case but I'm experimenting with another message queue currently